# wso2is: Is there a way to remove a token

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2is5.5. WSO2is stores sccess tokens in the database and caches them in memory. If you want to get rid of an token you must remove the token from database and restart the server. My question is, if there is a way to do this without restarting the server? Especially if some claim data has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the OAuth 2.0 token revocation [1] would fulfill your requirement you can use the WSO2 IS revoke endpoint to do that as below,

```
curl -X POST --basic -u "<client id>:<client secret>" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -k -d "token=<token to revoke>&token_type_hint=access_token" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/revoke
```

The Token Revocation defines a mechanism for clients to indicate to the authorization server that an access token is no longer needed. Please refer the documentation [2] for more details.

[1] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/OAuth2+Token+Revocation

Comment: Is there a way to remove the token by using the oidc/logout interface?

Comment: @csbrogi invoking `oidc/logout` endpoint won't revoke the access tokens